# Create another column based on the conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need help to create a query for this output below. As you can see in the below dataset, I wanted to have the patient record in a single row with all the details

[image: Dataset]

For example, Shahin Adam need to have only 1 single record combine the details of Dose Number 1 and Dose Number 2 with the date of each dose

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

[image: DESIRED OUTPUT]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Look up pivoting or conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select lastname, firstname,
       max(case when dosenumber = 1 then dosenumber end) as dosenumber_1,
       max(case when dosenumber = 1 then timeofevent end) as timeofevent_1,
       max(case when dosenumber = 2 then dosenumber end) as dosenumber_2,
       max(case when dosenumber = 2 then timeofevent end) as timeofevent_2
from t
group by lastname, firstname;
```

Answer (score 2):

As per desired output result section show only 2 records whose first name starts with A. That's why where clause is enabled here. If all patients info need then disable where clause.

```
SELECT PatientLastName, PatientFirstName
     , MAX(CASE WHEN DoseNumber = 1 THEN DoseNumber ELSE NULL END) DoseNumber1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN DoseNumber = 1 THEN TimeOfEvent ELSE NULL END) TimeOfEvent1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN DoseNumber = 2 THEN DoseNumber ELSE NULL END) DoseNumber2
     , MAX(CASE WHEN DoseNumber = 2 THEN TimeOfEvent ELSE NULL END) TimeOfEvent2
FROM table_name
WHERE PatientFirstName like 'A%'
GROUP BY PatientLastName, PatientFirstName
ORDER BY PatientFirstName;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow, this is a copy of other answer, with better look like. please read help center for give best feedback in stack.